# Sufficient condition on Matrix factorization

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix  $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and I want to identify a sufficient condition s.th $\exists P \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$, $k$ very small compared with $n$, and $M=PP^{T}$.

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Comment: I did not find a starting point to solve this problem.

Comment: @NairouzMrabah The condition is that this holds if and only if $P$ is positive semidefinite with rank at most $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a matrix exists if and only if $M$ is (symmetric and) positive semidefinite of rank at most $k$.

If $M = PP^T$, then we see that $\operatorname{rank}(M) \leq \operatorname{rank}(P)$ and that $M$ is indeed positive semidefinite, hence the necessity of the condition.  To show necessity, we could use the existence of a [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

Comment: Normally the Cholesky factorization is only defined for positive definite (full rank) matrices.

Comment: @Brian It tends not to be nice to compute directly, but such a decomposition certainly exists. See this [subsection of the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Proof_for_positive_semi-definite_matrices).

Comment: In computational practice, routines for Cholesky factorization tend to fail badly on positive semidefinite singular matrices.  Eigenvalue decomposition (treating tiny positive or negative eigenvalues as effectively 0) is a more reliable approach.